# Java InaccessibleWSDLException while accessing WSDL through client stubs

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, exchangewebservices

I am trying to write custom Java client for Exchange Web Services.
I have generated client stubs using `wsimport` tool as explained [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world) from EWS's Services.wsdl file. And now I have written code that uses these stubs. I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2   counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://host.domain.com/ews/Services.wsdl while opening stream from https://host.domain.com/ews/Services.wsdl
java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://host.domain.com/ews/Services.wsdl?wsdl while opening stream from https://host.domain.com/ews/Services.wsdl?wsdl

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.ExchangeWebService.<init>(ExchangeWebService.java:58)
at com.xyz.abc.EWSJavaAPI.ExchangeAuthenticator.getExchangeServicePort(ExchangeAuthenticator.java:33)
at com.xyz.abc.test.ExchangeDevelopmentTest.main(ExchangeDevelopmentTest.java:35)
```

As we can see above `ExchangeDevelopmentTest` is a client that uses another class `ExchangeAuthenticator` which in turn uses generated client stub `ExchangeWebService`. But up in the stack trace I got errors from Unknown Sources presumably JDKs' JARs.

The `IOException` says it got `HTTP response code: 401`, that is for unauthorized access. But I have correctly specified the user name and password and also have included the needed certificate in the keystore. I am totally directionless where this exception is coming from.

Code of the classes I wrote:

**ExchangeAuthenticator**

```
public class ExchangeAuthenticator {    
/**
 * Obtains an authenticated ExchangeServicePortType with given credentials.
 *     
 */
    public ExchangeServicePortType getExchangeServicePort(String username, String password, String domain, URL wsdlURL) throws MalformedURLException {
        // Concatinate our domain and username for the UID needed in authentication.
        String uid = "domain" + "\\" + "uname";

        // Create an ExchangeWebService object that uses the supplied WSDL file, wsdlURL.
        ExchangeWebService exchangeWebService = new ExchangeWebService(wsdlURL, new QName("<a href=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\">http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages</a>", "ExchangeWebService"));
        ExchangeServicePortType port = exchangeWebService.getExchangeWebPort();
        // Supply your username and password when the ExchangeServicePortType is used for binding in the SOAP request.
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, uid);
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

        return port;
    }
}
```

**ExchangeDevelopmentTest**

```
public class ExchangeDevelopmentTest {    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ExchangeAuthenticator exchangeAuthenticator = new ExchangeAuthenticator();

        // Print statement so we can easily see where our statements start in the Java console.
        System.out.println("Let's get started!");

        try {
            // Create a URL object which points at the .wsdl we deployed in the previous step.
            URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://172.17.245.196/ews/Services.wsdl");
            //URL wsdlURL = new URL("<a href=\"https://172.17.245.196/ews/Services.wsdl\">https://172.17.245.196/ews/Services.wsdl</a>");
            // Call to the class we just created to return an ExchangeServicePortType with authentication credentials.
            ExchangeServicePortType port = exchangeAuthenticator.getExchangeServicePort("uname", "password@123", "domain", wsdlURL);

            // Prints out the default toString() for the ExchangeServicePortType.
            System.out.println(port.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            // Catch any errors that may occur.
            Logger.getLogger(ExchangeDevelopmentTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage()+"\n"+ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

**ExchangeWebService**

Generated by JAX-WS with `wsimport` tool, other constructors and methods removed. Only contructor at line 58 which calls `super` (here `Service` class) constructor is kept.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "ExchangeWebService", targetNamespace =     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Services.wsdl")
public class ExchangeWebService extends Service
{ 
    private final static URL EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", "ExchangeWebService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new         URL("file:/C:/workspace/Server%20files/Client%20files/Services.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        EXCHANGEWEBSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    //other constructos & methods removed
    //line 58
    public ExchangeWebService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

*Why* access the remote WSDL document file (and schema files) when you can have a **local copy**? Of course, security is still required to access the endpoint.

First, you need the class loader according to the environment.

```
// Java EE Enviroment
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

// Java Standalone Enviroment
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

Next, store locally a copy of the WSDL document file (and the scheme files if needed) in your project.

```
URL wsdlLocation = cl.getResource("com/mahesha999/ExchangeWebService.wsdl");
QName qName = new QName(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", 
    "ExchangeWebService"
);

ExchangeWebService exchangeWebService = new ExchangeWebService(wsdlLocation, 
        qName);
ExchangeServicePortType port = exchangeWebService.getExchangeWebPort();
```

If authentication is required to access the webservice endpoint, in its most basic form, is as follows:

```
BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> context = provider.getRequestContext();
context.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
context.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
```

If you need to deal with certificates and that sort of thing, better have a look at [*Securing WebLogic Web Services*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13713/toc.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Did you add username and password this way?

```
    ShopingCart sc = scs.getShopingCartPort();
    Map requestContext = ((BindingProvider)sc).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);
    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
```

You have not given your client code in question.  Are you using proxy?  Then you have to give your proxy username and password in the above.

Comment: I have added the code. As you can see  `ExchangeDevelopmentTest` contains the `main()`. And in `ExchangeAuthenticator` at line `ExchangeWebService exchangeWebService...` I am getting Exception. This line simply calling one of the constructor of `ExchangeWebService` class (generated by `wsimport` tool) which in turn calls `super` (here `Service` class) constructor. While debuging I cant get into source of this class (obviously).

Comment: In that constructor for the second parameter use QName how autogenerated code has provided.  `new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", "ExchangeWebService")`